# Mysql unique index for voting system

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, unique-constraint

In a table for recording votes on posts as

```
CREATE TABLE votes
(
vote_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
post_id int(11) REFERENCES posts(post_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
user_id int(11) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
vote ENUM('Up', 'Down'),
ip varchar(255),
UNIQUE INDEX (on which???)
PRIMARY KEY(vote_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

How to add `UNIQUE INDEX` to avoid duplicate voting? If the voter is user, UNIQUE INDEX should apply to (post_id, user_id); and if not a user, UNIQUE INDEX should apply to (post_id, ip).

In fact, I need to have `UNIQUE INDEX` only for (post_id, user_id) OR (post_id, ip); but NOT both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to normalize: Create another field like `vote_src VARCHAR(15)`, that gets either the user or the IP from your code and create a unique index on this.

Comment: very nice trick; though it will increase the storage volume due to a duplicate column!

Comment: Sure it will, but chosing between the storage and the uglyness of all other possibilities, I'd go for the storage. Keep in Mind, that a VARCHAR(15) is 18 bytes max, so 1 million votes will be 18 megabytes ...

Comment: you're quite right! but I wished to find another way, as vote column rapidly increases (in order of millions, a casting every vote).

Comment: @Ali If you have millions of votes per day, then perofrmance is much more important than storage - in this case, the "simple" index with the additional column will perform much better than any "tricky" index.

Answer (score 3):

**Revised following further information** To do specifically as you request I would advise the following.  Add a source table to further normalise

```
CREATE TABLE vote_sources (
    source_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    // 0 will be treated as anonymous, as NULL can have issues on UNIQUE indexes
    user_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE SET 0,
    ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    dupeCheck VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(source_id),
    UNIQUE INDEX (dupeCheck)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE votes
(
    vote_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id int(11) REFERENCES posts(post_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    source_id int(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES vote_sources(source_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    vote ENUM('Up', 'Down'),
    PRIMARY KEY(vote_id),
    UNIQUE INDEX(post_id,source_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

And then to deal with dupe checks this triggere

```
CREATE TRIGGER dupeSourceCheck
BEFORE INSERT ON vote_sources
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.dupeCheck = IF(NEW.user_id>0,CAST(NEW.user_id AS CHAR),NEW.ip)
```

Which in turn should cause a duplicate key error if a duplicate source is detailed, while still exposing a numeric user_id for more efficient joins.

Comment: 1) the first case only index duplicate votes by users, and the second one will not consider user_id. 2) the storage size of varchar(15) and varchar(255) is equal.

Comment: The storage size of VARCHAR(15) and VARCHAR(255) is equal as the field storage size is StringLength+1 byte for strings up to 255 bytes, however an IP will not have over 15 characters and so there is no need to have a field larger than you need as it can lead to indexes having issues.

Comment: definitely, it is better to use varchar(15) when longer field is not needed. Thanks for reminding me, and surely I will update my code; I just meant it is not my serious concern at this time :)

Comment: The longer you leave it, the more difficult it'll become to change, better to optimise while making other changes rather than put it off until another day ;)

Comment: down? me? I always appreciate the time people spend to answer!

Comment: +1 This however will allow two or more votes from same user - with different IPs.

Comment: Good point, gotta love questions that are open to interpretation.  Maybe something along the lines of what Eugen Riek suggested then, though that's rather ugly.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have PHPMyAdmin? This is very easy to do there. Do you want a field to be a PRIMARY KEY or do you truly want just a UNIQUE index? If you have PHPMyAdmin as an option you can go to your structure tab and at the bottom you will see an indexes table with a choice to add an index. Click 'GO' and walla! You have your index.

Comment: what are you talking about? It is not matter of how to edit, I am talking about the table structure. P.S. I never use PHPMyAdmin, as command line is my old friend ;)